# ASP.NET Core Package giving me warring

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While Installing a new package in my project, I'm getting the following warning

> Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project

Comment: the warning is pretty clear and self explanatory that .NET framework package got installed in .NET core project which of-course will not work

Comment: off-course that is..But how to get rid of it !

Comment: I think their is no concept of packages in .NET Framework but .dll. files. .NET Core involves packages concept.

Comment: Aaaaand? What's the solution when you have .net and dotnet core side by side?